# How to format part of a figure caption in MS Word bold, and the other part regular?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, text-formatting, styles, caption

I would like to generate figure captions as displayed in the image below.

---

[image]

---

The figure caption should contain 3 parts:

- Part 1: Automatic numbering including chapter number and figure number. Font: Bold
- Part 2: The first sentence is a figure heading formatted in Bold.
- Part 3. The rest of the text is the figure description and should be formatted as "regular" (not bold).

So far I only achieved to automatically format Part 1 as "bold" by defining the "Captions"-Style. Then I can manually type the Part 2 in Bold. I can now also manually select "regular" font to type Part 3.

But as soon as I update fields, the complete figure caption is formatted in bold.

Is there a way to define Part 3 as "regular" without it changing back to "bold"? I heard there might be a possibility of using macros. I am not experienced with this, however. But if there is a good tutorial, I would be able to follow.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You would want to use a [Style Separator](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator).

*(The link above is to a spot in my website.)*

You would create a new style called Caption Plain which would be the same formatting as your normal or body text style. The Caption style itself would be bold. You would have the parts you want in bold in that style. Press the carriage return and use the Caption Plain style. Then return to the end of the caption and use the Style Separator.

The screenshot below, from my page, shows this being used with a Heading Style.

[image: screenshot using style separator]

On a Mac, you would use a regular paragraph break marked as hidden.

**Note:** The text in the Caption Plain style will not be shown in a [Table of Figures](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures). *link to my site*

In the definition of your Caption style, you could make the Caption Plain style the style for the following paragraph. After inserting the Caption, go to the end of the paragraph, press Enter and add your non-bold text which will be in the Caption Plain style. Then insert your Style Separator.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's amazing. This works perfectly! After years of headache about this, there is finally a solution!!

Comment: Did I understand rightly that only the part before the style separator will be included in the Table of Figures?

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Sorry in case I haven't communicated this clearly, but that is actually the effect I was looking for. In the List of Figures I am aiming to include only the bold-typed Figure heading and not the regular-typed Figure description.

Comment: It does not matter how they look in the document. They could look the same. What matters is that they have different paragraph styles applied.

Comment: Yes. The important thing is they have different styles applied and in addition the plain text does not show in the figure legend, only the bold "figure heading" which is a positive side effect that helps me as well.

Comment: I've observed one issue with the style applied after the Style Separator. Somehow the text after the Style Separator for only that part of paragraph does not get spell-checked. I checked the settings in "Modify Style", "Format", "Language", and the box "Do not check spelling or grammar" is unchecked. Is there any other cause? Any idea how to fix? **Update:** It seems like I can induce the spell-checking if I select the text which is not being checked and click again on applying the style defined for after the Style Separator. It's weird, because the correct style is already highlighted before.

Comment: To continue my comment from before: What happens is basically that after placing the style separator, the correct style is automatically chosen, but when I type some text, spell-checking does not work for the text following the style separator. I can start the spell-checking if I highlight the text not being checked and click on applying the same style that is already automatically applied.

Comment: Link to sample? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: Hi, I uploaded a sample on file.io: https://file.io/Dr1axo9W6mKN
And here is a screenshot of the problem: https://i.ibb.co/DzxLYMP/Screenshot-2021-05-05-183824.png
Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate this.

Comment: File was deleted.

Comment: New link: https://easyupload.io/clw6ov
This should provide the file for at lest 30 days. Hope this works.

Comment: I reviewed it and you are right. Not only that, but per reveal formatting, this text is marked with the language attribute: Do not check spelling or grammar! http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#RevealCodes This is not the normal behavior of the Style Separator! Try in a different document. Here is my sample (temp link) https://www.dropbox.com/s/npzj98e2p8637lh/deleteme%20style%20separator%20sample.docx?dl=0

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the feedback. In your sample it is indeed working flawlessly. Do you have any advice how to correct my document? I tried highlighting the complete document and click on the language hyperlink in the reveal formatting pane. I can de-select "do not check spelling or grammar". It can only correct already typed text. Next time I use the style separator, the same issue appears again. It is weird that it is affecting only one style...

Comment: If you want this resolved, first try in a new document. If that does not help, to get the best help, start a new question about this problem, possibly with a link back here.

Comment: @AJZ203, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Thank you very much! I already accepted your answer on May 4th. As I am a relatively new user, I can't vote on posts, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Word uses the style called "Caption" for captions and will apply it to the whole
text. Word cannot do complex styles that are part bold and part regular.

I think that the solution would be to modify the `Caption` style so it becomes
harmless and will leave alone your manual styling of the text.

I have not tested my following idea:

- [Create a new style](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563)
  called for example "mycaption" that does something harmless like setting the font
- Modify the Caption style to be based on "mycaption":

  - In *Home > Styles* pane, click the little icon at the bottom-right
  - In the Styles dialog, click the Manage Style icon (bottom third-left)
  - Find "Caption" in the list and click it
  - Click "Modify..."
  - Set "Style based on:" to your style "mycaption"
  - Click OK.

If this works, you will still need to set in bold the text part manually
for each figure, but this will not change when Word updates the style
of the text to "Caption".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your help very much. This approach is definitely worth exploring, but the solution of Charles Kenyon using a Style Separator definitely solves the problem by its roots.