# How to make caption text style different from the caption label and numbering?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, caption

I want my image caption to look like this:

[image: image caption style]

I make the caption's style to align center, font size 10, font TNR, and Bold. I want the caption text to have the same style but without the Bold. I have to un-bold it manually every time I add new caption, is there anyway to make it automated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format part of a figure caption in MS Word bold, and the other part regular?](https://superuser.com/questions/1646419/how-to-format-part-of-a-figure-caption-in-ms-word-bold-and-the-other-part-regul)

Comment: @Ramhound not really because I want the caption text still included in the Table of Figures

Answer (score 0):

### You would want to use a [Style Separator](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator).

*(The link above is to a spot in my website.)* This is as close to Automated as you will get short of very finicky vba code.

You would create a new style called Caption Plain which would be the same formatting as your normal or body text style. The Caption style itself would be bold. You would have the parts you want in bold in that style. Press the carriage return and use the Caption Plain style. Then return to the end of the caption and use the Style Separator.

The screenshot below, from my page, shows this being used with a Heading Style.

[image: screenshot using style separator]

On a Mac, you would use a regular paragraph break marked as hidden.

**Note:** The text in the Caption Plain style will not be shown in a [Table of Figures](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures). *link to my site*

In the definition of your Caption style, you could make the Caption Plain style the style for the following paragraph. After inserting the Caption, go to the end of the paragraph, press Enter and add your non-bold text which will be in the Caption Plain style. Then insert your Style Separator.

*Note that this is essentially a recap of my answer to a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1646419/how-to-format-part-of-a-figure-caption-in-ms-word-bold-and-the-other-part-regul/1646600#1646600).*